# bootstrap switch handlewidth issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been playing with bootstrap handlewidth but everything else works except this attribute. I want to increase the size of the button.

When I change handleWidth attribute, it does nothing

Please check this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sumw4/1479/

```
$('.probeProbe').bootstrapSwitch({
     'state': true,
     'size' : 'normal',
     'labelText': "demo",
     'handleWidth': 1000 //I want to increase the size of handleWidth
});
```

On the website/Wiki, this works: http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/examples.html

I am not sure why it's not working. Can someone help? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your jsfiddle, you're referencing an old version (3.0.1) of bootstrap-switch. Change the reference to the current version, 3.3.2

```
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-switch/3.3.2/js/bootstrap-switch.js
```

and it works perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/sumw4/1481/